# Text on image mouseover like youtube

Tags: javascript, text, mouseover

How can I show text on top of my images when a mouse moves over them.

For example you see on youtube you have an add to playlist button on the thumbnails. How can I setup something similar but for a like button.

I am not looking for a tooltip. I want the text to shown on the image when the mouse is hovered over it.

Comment: You could consider the `title` HTML attribute if you're looking for something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each of your images inside a seperate "container" div. These divs should have the position: relative attribute. Give all the images the class name 'singleImage'  Put another div inside of this each of the "container" divs with position: absolute and display none. Set the class name for these divs to 'toolTip'. This div will be the tooltip. Put a title attribute on your images. You will need jQuery to rig up the hovering or plain javascript if your feeling adventurous

In jQuery you would do something like:

```
$('.singleImage').mouseover(function(){
    var tt = $(this).parent().find('.toolTip');
    tt.html($(this).attr('title'));
    tt.show();
});
$('.singleImage').mouseout(function(){
    var tt = $(this).parent().find('.toolTip');
    tt.hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) I think

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are referring to is called a "tooltip".  There are plenty of different plugins ciruclating out there that you may be able to utilize.  Without having specific code, it will be hard for anyone to present a tailor-made solution.